# How can I practice not blundering in the opening?

Tags: opening, opening-traps, memorization

For a couple days now I have been searching for a way to practice openings. I do not want to memorize a specific opening, I want to exercise in responding to my opponent.

I'm looking for some kind of tool or software where I ideally can practice as follows:
We start a game and the computer plays `1. e4`. I respond with `1...e5`. Since that is a move by the book, the tool makes another move, for example, `2. Qh5`. I than blunder with the move `2...g6`. Now the software tells me that that is a (very) bad move, and it does that by showing to me what happens next: '*`3. Qxe5+` and you lose your rook to a fork. Play `2...Nc6` instead.*'
The game than rewinds to `2. Qh5` and we continue from there or maybe we start over and now after `1. e4 e5` I need to not blunder against `2. Nf3`.

##### So what I want:

- I play an opening against a computer
- The computer responds with different moves (not just with one opening)
- When I make a blunder/a move that isn't theory, the computer tells me
- We continue play till we 'finished' the book moves

If there isn't some kind of tool out there with theory moves included, it would also be ok if I could enter some openings my self:

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6
1. e4 e5 2. Qh5 Nc6
1. e4 e5 2. Qh5 g6?? 3. Qxe5+
```

Than the computer always plays something from this list and warns me when I play something not on the list or a blunder.

##### What I came up with myself

Now I have heard of https://openings.chessbase.com/ but I found it a bit daunting so I don't really know if it can do what I want or not.